# Why isn't clorhexidine gluconate used among humans?

Tags: infection, drug-metabolism, disinfection

It is used for non-human animals, but as far as I have read it is not used among people. Are there exceptions?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, it's used by humans all the time. Hibiclens, Dyna-Ex, used as an oral rinse...

Comment: The answer to the question: Because it's usually referred to by brand name instead of generic chemical name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used among humans [it's called](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMHT0009564/?report=details):

> Hibiclens, Dyna-Hex, Ezy-tm, and Exidine

As also stated by the user JohnP in a comment.

And it works for:

- Cleaning the hands
- Before surgery or injections
- To cleanse skin or wounds
- And as a oral rinse

***So there is no exception it is used for humans.***

- But you are right it is also used for [animals](http://www.drugs.com/vet/chlorhexidine-solution.html).